# What is the standard definition of a "periodic" function?

Tags: functions, definition

This question is admittedly pedantic, but I like my definitions precise.

Tom Apostol, in his calculus book, defines a periodic function as follows.

> A function *f* is said to be *periodic* with period $p \neq 0$ if its domain contains $x+p$ whenever it contains $x$ and if $f(x+p) = f(x)$ for every $x$ in the domain of $f$.

This is slightly unclear to me.

Let $g:[0, 32\pi] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $g(x) = \sin(x)$. By this definition, $g$ is not periodic with $2\pi$; this is counter-intuitive, however.

Comment: Bourbaki (*Topologie*, VII.1.6, Définition 1) defines the concept only for functions defined throughout $\mathbf{R}$ (actually, $\mathbf{R}^n$). The same is true in Cours de mathématiques spéciales by Ramis, Odoux, Deschamps (Tome 3, p. 14). Personally, I'm surprised Apostol doesn't require the function to be defined at $x-p$ as well.

Comment: Well, it's years too late but according to Apostols definition a period function repeats *forever*.  Your example only repeats $16$ times.... That said Apostols definition has of few weird things to me. It allows for negative periods. It allows for a period function to "start" but not "end". A function doesn't have a basic single period. If $p$ is a period of $f$ then so is $kp$ for all natural $k$.  (And a constant function has "all" periods?)

Answer (score 1):

Let $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ and $f:A\rightarrow B$ be a function. We say that $f$ is **periodic with period $p\in \mathbb R$** if for any $a_{1},a_{2}\in A$,

$$a_{1}-a_{2}=kp\text{ for some }k\in\mathbb{Z} \implies  f\left(a_{1}\right)=f\left(a_{2}\right).$$

Comment: Why did you answer this? That is exactly what the OP says Apostol says and the OP didn't understand it.

Comment: @fleablood: Why did you post your comment? My definition is different from the quoted Apostol one.

Answer (score 0):

A periodic function, as I know it, is nothing but a function that repeats its values after certain intervals. Or, if $f(x+np)=f(x) \, \forall n \in \mathbb{Z}$ whenever it is defined. The definition you're referring to is dealing with periodicity in the real line or equivalent. To be precise, we say that the functions have a single period (as opposed to $f(x)=0$ and such) i.e. $f(x)-f(y)=0 \implies x-y=np$ for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: If here's a function : $f(x+1/ n)=f(x),\forall n>0$,is it a period function?

Comment: @Benjamin No. You cannot find a $p$ such that it's true for any $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.